# Fill two-dimensional array with boolean value

Tags: java, android, arrays

In my class I have these properties:

```
boolean rendered[][] = new boolean[][]{};
String tabs[] = { "Tab 1", "Tab 2" };
int rows = 10;
```

... and I want to create an array with two main levels (two elements in `tabs` array), and each level would have 10 (variable `rows`) elements with `false` value.

Answer (score 5):

You are free to think of it as [row][column] or [column][row] but the former has a history of usage.

```
int rows = 10, int columns = 2
boolean rendered[][] = new boolean[rows][columns];
java.util.Arrays.fill(rendered[0], false);
java.util.Arrays.fill(rendered[1], false);
```

Comment: `boolean` (not `Boolean`) arrays are by default filled with `false`. Last two lines are only required if we want to reset already used array, or set values to `true`.

Comment: The more you know, I learned something from answering a question ;)

Comment: How do you declare that type of Array as a class field?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should tell the compiler how long is your array:

```
boolean rendered[][] = new Boolean[4][5];
```

Then you can proceed filling it

```
for(int i = 0; i < rendered.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < rendered[i].length; j++)
        rendered[i][j] = false;
```

Comment: If you use `boolean rendered[][] = new boolean[4][5];` you won't need to iterate over entire array because every element for `boolean` array is by default set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [`Arrays#fill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28boolean%5B%5D,%20boolean%29):

```
boolean rendered[][] = new boolean[rows][columns]; // you have to specify the size here
for(boolean row[]: rendered)
    Arrays.fill(row, false);
```

(`Arrays#fill` can only work on a one-dimensional array, so you'll have to iterate over the rest of the dimensions in a `for` loop yourself.)